# SSH Connection from docker container to EXTERNAL server to read MySQL Database (query from docker)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, ssh

I think there are alot of 'kind of my solution' questions and answer, but it is not THE answer to my solution. I'm pretty new to Docker, the new company I work at works with it. I know my way around PHP pretty well and making a SSH connection should not be too hard either.

But still: I just can't figure it out.

I am using Laradock to run the docker containers.

So what I have done:

```
docker-compose up -d nginx php-fm mysql elasticsearch
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id name@server.com
```

Then I SSH directly from the workshop like this

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash
ssh -L *or* -R name@server.com
```

I can get the connection, AND I can do mysql on that server when logged in.

But: When I try to connect through my Laravel/PHP application:

```
$dbServerHost = 'ipofserver';
shell_exec("ssh -fNg -R 3316:$dbServerHost:3306 name@server");
$username = 'usernameofDB';
$password = 'PasswordOfDB';
$dbname = 'DatabaseName';
$connection = new mysqli($dbServerHost, $username, $password, $dbname, 3316);
```

It gives me: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused, time and time again. I am pretty much lost here. I also used a laravel ssh tunnel but that was more confusing than it is now. As this tunnel used it's own database env attributes to connect to an external database.

I am probably missing something really simple here.

Comment: Can you give the actual error message it gives.

Comment: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the PHP code.
Used the phpseclib package (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib)

And changed it to.

```
$ssh = new SSH2('server.com');
    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pPass -e "SELECT * FROM db.measurements LIMIT 30" ');
```

Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You're running SSH under different user's in this case.

```
// this runs as root or whatever user you've setup to login to the container with
docker-compose exec workspace bash
ssh -L *or* -R name@server.com

// this is running as the web server's user, likely www-data
$dbServerHost = 'ipofserver';
shell_exec("ssh -fNg -R 3316:$dbServerHost:3306 name@server");
$username = 'usernameofDB';
$password = 'PasswordOfDB';
$dbname = 'DatabaseName';
$connection = new mysqli($dbServerHost, $username, $password, $dbname, 3316);
```

You need to setup your web server user in the same fashion that you did normally with:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id name@server.com
```

Basically you need to generate an ssh key for `www-data` (or whatever the web server runs under) and add that to the destination server's `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!
I get it alot better now. I need to do all the SSH things from the server and not as root user.